# How can I add Number of records in Tableau as it is missing?

Tags: tableau-api

In my Tableau book the measure Number of Records is missing. How can I add it?

Hi Stackoverflow,
In my Tableau book the measure Number of Records is missing. How can I add it?
I've tried using "Create Calculated Field" with the value 1, but it is gives me count of records as 1.

Kind regards,
Anna

Comment: Please elaborate properly.  If you'll add a calc field as 1, it will show up as 1 only.  You can however sum this field as per context

Answer (score 0):

Beginning tableau 2020.2, tableau has changed many things.

To cite directly from tableau's web portal... "You will no longer see the Number of Records field in data sources that contain logical tables. Every table includes a count of its records, as a field named TableName(Count), at the level of detail for that table."

I think this will surely help you and solves your problem.

In a nutshell only the name has been changed, that field is there itself.

Still If you want to use it through Calculated Field.. `1`, you may perhaps have forgotten to convert it to measure `sum` OR `count` to show the number of records.

Comment: Thank you, yes, it is there. The attribute called `tmdb_movies_data.csv(Count)`. Many thanks for your answer. To calculate it I use formula: `count([Id])`

Comment: @Anna, I'm glad that it helped.  You can add a count field in a better way instead.  Use sum of a claculated field with just `1` in it.  Please upvote if you think so. https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote

Answer (score 0):

Create a new calculated field with 1. [This post](https://tarsolutions.co.uk/blog/number-of-records-missing-in-tableau/) gives full details about the missing number of records.

Answer (score -1):

I created a calculated field and named it "No of records" an assigned the syntax: count([ID])